# how can i store the return value of a future in a variable?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'd like to know how can i store in a variable in the state of the application the return value of a future in a flutter app ?
For example :
`List usernames = await AuthMethods().getCurrentUserInvitations()`
Where the method getCurrentUserInvitations returns a list.
I only get the instance not the actual return of the future.

```
Future<List> getCurrentUserInvitations() async {
    List usernames = [];
    try {
      var snap = await _firestore
          .collection("users")
          .doc(_auth.currentUser!.uid)
          .get();
      print(snap.data()!["invitedBy"]);
      snap.data()!["invitedBy"].forEach((invitedById) async {
        try {
          var snap =
              await _firestore.collection("users").doc(invitedById).get();
          print(snap.data()!["username"]);
          usernames.add(snap.data()!["username"]);
        } catch (e) {
          print(e.toString());
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
    return usernames;
  }
```

added the code from the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to just store the future into a variable, there is a pretty straight forward way to do that. In your code, change it to

```
Future<List> usernames = AuthMethods().getCurrentUserInvitations()
```

And then, when you want to access the data returned in the Future, you will have to wait for that Future to get completed. For example, if you want to calculate the length of the List, do

```
Future<List> usernames = AuthMethods().getCurrentUserInvitations()
.
.
.
   /* ... Code that doesn't need value of usernames ... */
.
.
.
/* Then when you want the actual values, */
List actualUsernames = await usernames;
print(actualUsernames.length);
```

Comment: in fact im trying to execute the method getCurrentUserInvitations() and store the return value in the usernames list since i'm also returning a list from the method. I d'ont even know if this is possible tbh

Comment: I'd like to be able to do a usernames.length for example. i just want it to have the value of the return of the future, the list

Comment: @ArnaudNaNo It all depends on whether the method returns a future or not. Looking at your original code, since you are using await, I am assuming it is returning a Future. But more importantly, from your words, I feel that you don't have absolute clarity about how Future works. In that case, please refer to some documentation/resources to get some clarity.

Comment: @ArnaudNaNo So, you want to do usernames.length, where usernames is a Future? You cant, unless you wait till the future is completed and you get the actual data. Do `List nonFutureActualUsernames = await usernames` after the code in the answer, when you want the future's values to be used.

Comment: i added the code of the method to be clear

Comment: Edited the answer to match the question.